# Partitions are still showing in hive even though they are dropped for an external table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, impala

I have an external table in hive partitioned by year, month, day. So I dropped one partition but I still see it in show partitions.

```
>use test_raw_tables;
>show partitions test1_raw;
[year=2016/month=01/day=01]
[year=2017/month=03/day=24]

> alter table test1_raw drop partition (year=2016, month=01, day=01);
> refresh test1_raw;
> show partitions test1_raw;
[year=2016/month=01/day=01]
[year=2017/month=03/day=24]     ---Still see the dropped partition here----

> msck repair table test1_raw;
> show partitions test1_raw;
[year=2016/month=01/day=01]
[year=2017/month=03/day=24]    ---Still see the dropped partition here----
```

Running from impala with hive as engine.

> describe test1_raw 
>   col_name,data_type,comment ('amount_hold', 'int', '') ('id', 'int', '') ('transaction_id', 'string', '') ('recipient_id', 'string', '') ('year', 'string', '') ('month', 'string', '') ('day', 'string', '') ('', None, None) ('# Partition Information', None, None) ('# col_name ', 'data_type ', 'comment ') ('', None, None) ('year', 'string', '') ('month', 'string', '') ('day', 'string', '') 
>   location 'hdfs://localhost/sys/datalake/testing/test1_raw'

What is the problem here?
The data in hdfs is deleted for that partition after dropping it. Cannot figure out the issue.

Comment: **(1)** please add the table definition **(2)** from where are you running your code? impala-shell? hive? beeline?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Table is an external table. Running the query from hive shell.

Comment: `refresh` is as Impala command, not hive. I need to know what are you executing from where as well as the table definition, including the relevant partitions definition. Please also show me how their paths looks like in the file system.

Comment: Please Add this to the post as well as the paths of the relevant partitions

Answer (score 1):

In your Table defination Column Year, Month and Day are in String format.
Pls try with '2016', '01' and '01'.
I used below code and it works.

```
alter table test1_raw drop partition (year='2016', month='01', day='01');
```

Comment: please make the answer as correct if it works for you

Comment: I guess that's a bug from Hive that msck repair doesn't remove the deleted partitions on its own(Table is external means Hive really doesn't have that ownership, but still it doesn't work). But deleting partitions by alter table command works.

Answer (score 0):

Not that it matters anymore but you changed a definition of a table.  You didn't change the data.  Hive is unique in that it will let you define schema on read, altering the definition is just altering the definition it's not changing the data only the table definition.  You can have multiple tables sit on top of the same data without issues, it doesn't mean a table definition change in one affects the other. (Well I'm talking about On READ anyways...)